# Filter Content Search WebPart on libraries with the same name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-search, content-search-web-part

I have a site template that has a library called ContentLibrary. I want to do a search that returns only item and document results from those libraries that are in various sites and site collections. I tried using contains with Path and ListURL but both return no documents. Path:/ContentLibrary/ ListURL:/ContentLibrary/

How can I filter on library name or use a contains for a URL?

Is there a way to do it with result sources?

**Update 1**
Created a new result source using ListURL:ContentLibary and it returns all the libraries needed but not the items inside.

**Update 2**
I thought I was going to be able to just do this in the query for the CSWP. `ListUrl:ContentLibrary (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True) owstaxidmetadataalltagsinfo:{QueryString.MyParameter1}`

ListUrl only seems to only allow the return of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx) to create a new result source which limit search results within same name document library and items in it:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it without explicitly naming each list/library? There's currently 15 and I expect it to grow over 150

Answer (score 0):

I am coming to the conclusion that there is no way to construct this query as intended. My next endeavor is to create a content type hub and add a published content type to that library in the site template. That should allow me to filter on a single content type id. Unfortunately I'll have to update all the items to the new content type... I'll continue to pursue this solution and update it in case is works. Would happily take someone else's solution to this though.